# Questionmark meaning in a SAPUI5 MessageBox property

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm lacking to understand the following code

```
var viewCompact = !!this.getView().$().closest(".sapUiSizeCompact").length;
        MessageBox.information(this.oRessourceBundle.getText("CSC_INFO"), {
            styleClass: viewCompact ? "sapUiSizeCompact" : "" //what is the question mark doing here?
        });
    },
```

what does the questionmark mean in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark is a ternary, Its basically a shorthand if-else statement, you could type it out as the following:

```
if(viewCompact){
   return "sapUiSizeCompact"
}else{
  return ""
}
```